# HTTP: One object per line in the response's body

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I am supposed to make a API that returns "one JSON object per line in the response's body" like so:

`GET /somerequest`

response body:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2}
{"c": 1, "b": 3}
{"a": 4, "b": 2}
...
```

I have absolutely no clue on how to **cleanly** do that. What am I supposed to put in my `res.send(...)` ? 
Should I turn my Objects into strings, separate them with '\n' and then send back this string? That does not sound very clean.

I am quite new to Web dev, please forgive me if the answer is obvious.

EDIT1: maybe it is to be used as a [jsonlines](http://jsonlines.org) for better readability and ease of assessment.

Comment: *"Should I turn my Objects into a string, separate them with '\n' and then send back this string?"* – Yes. Also, tell whoever made that API spec that they're an incompetent buffoon.

Comment: Could I have misunderstood something? It's literally wirtten " `GET /export` return one JSON object per line" + the above  exemple

Comment: @JJJ There's absolutely nothing wrong with that response format.  Newline-delimited JSON is a commonly used thing, and saves quite a bit of resources when dealin with large numbers of records.

Comment: @Emilien You're writing the server in Node.js?  Where is this data coming from?  I'd use a transform stream and pipe it directly to `res`.

Comment: @Brad Yes I am and the data is coming from a neo4j db !

Comment: @Emilien Show some code in context of how you're querying your data, so we can provide a good answer for you.

Comment: @Brad Done ! (and many thanks for your time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truns out it is really easy to do as the http response is writable.

Here's an example reading data from a neo4j db using the bolt protocol.

```
(res, query) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
        'Trailer': 'Content-MD5'
    });
    const session = driver.session()
    session
        .run(query)
        .subscribe({
            onNext: function (record) {
                const newObj = { "whatever": recod.get("something") }
                res.write(JSON.stringify(newObj) + '\n')
                },
            onCompleted: function () {
                res.addTrailers({ 'Content-MD5': '7895bf4b8828b55ceaf47747b4bca667'})
                res.end()
                session.close();
            },
            onError: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                res.send({ success: false, message: error })
            }
        })
}
```